# Gaussian Random Matrix

Tags: random-matrices, gaussian

Let $X$ be an $n \times n$ symmetric matrix, whose entries are denoted as $X_{i j}, 1 \leq i, j \leq n .$ Suppose that all the entries on and above the diagonal are independent, i.e., the entries $X_{i j}, 1 \leq i \leq j \leq n$ are independent. Further assume that $X_{i i}$ has $N(0,2)$ distribution for every $1 \leq i \leq n,$ and $X_{i j}$ has $N(0,1)$ distribution for every $1 \leq i<j \leq n .$ Now let $U$ be an $n \times n$ orthogonal matrix, and let $Y=U^{T} X U .$ Clearly $Y$ is symmetric. Prove that all the entries on and above the diagonal of $Y$ are independent, and find the distributions of all these entries.

I have no ideas and can anyone help me?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: hint: Start from proving that the distributions are Gaussian. For Gaussian variables, independence can be determined by the behavior of the covariances.

Comment: @user619894 Thanks for your hint, you mean calculating the covariances? Would you please tell me more details?

Comment: By covariances I mean the cross correlations between the entries.